# VB.NET: Update DataGridView when DataSource DataTable is Updated

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I am having trouble getting my `DataGridView` to update when the `DataTable` in the  underlying `DataSource` is updated.

I have a class (imagine it is actually doing something worthwhile):

```
Public Class config

    Public Property inputsTable As DataTable
    Public Property outputsTable As DataTable

    Public Sub New()
        inputsTable = New DataTable
        outputsTable = New DataTable

        inputsTable.TableName = "inputs"
        inputsTable.Columns.Add("name")
        inputsTable.Columns.Add("value")

        outputsTable.TableName = "outputs"
        outputsTable.Columns.Add("name")
        outputsTable.Columns.Add("value")
    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadValuesFromConfig(newConfig As config)

        Me.inputsTable = newConfig.inputsTable
        Me.outputsTable = newConfig.outputsTable

        ' do stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

... which supports a `Form`:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Property thisConfig As config
    Public Property savedConfig As config

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        thisConfig = New config

        DataGridView1.DataSource = thisConfig.inputsTable
        DataGridView2.DataSource = thisConfig.outputsTable

    End Sub

    ' do stuff      

End Class
```

Although I have `DataGridView1` and `DataGridView2` bound to `myConfig.inputTable` and `myConfig.outputTable` respectively, if I update `myConfig.inputTable` or `myConfig.outputTable` via `myConfig.LoadValuesFromConfig`, the `DataGridView`s are not updated. (Is this because the data source lost the reference when I passed a new table in?)

Two methods I could think of:

1. Instead of `Me.inputsTable = newConfig.inputsTable`, could I do this?:

   ```
   Me.inputsTable.Rows.Clear()
   For Each row As DataRow In newConfig.inputsTable.Rows
       Me.inputsTable.ImportRow(row)
   Next
   ```
2. Create an Event in config that fires when the table is updated, and in `Form1` handle that event and reset the `DataSource` to `myConfig.inputsTable`

Any suggestions or better ideas would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this because the data source lost the reference when I passed a new table in?

Yes, that's why. In the `LoadValuesFromConfig` you destroy the reference to the existing tables.

There are quite a few option you have here.

First of all, it is far more flexible to put in a [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) in between the `DataGridView` and the `DataTables`

Second of all, instead of binding the `BindingSource` directly to the table, bind it to a [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the `DataMember` property to the name of your table.

Then you have several options to replace the data in your `DataTable` instances ,preferably using the instances supplied through `Tables` property of the DataSet.

1. You can use `ReadXml` where the complete tables is reloaded from an XML file.
2. You can use the `Load` method and supply some implementation of (a custom) `IDataReader`
3. Use the `Merge` method to merge another `DataTable` (with the same scheme)into the existing `DataTable`
4. Clear the rows and import all rows, although not very efficient.

I would advise you to start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) for using databinding in WinForms based on `DataSets` and `BindingSources`